# Housing zones not rebuilding

Tags: simcity-2013

One of my cities had a small accident (not an ingame disaster).
I went afk for a bit when i came back a lot of my houses had burnt down or were abandoned, so i destroyed them.

My problem now is that none of the buildings are being rebuilt.
I have tried unzoning and rezoning it but with no luck.
Both residential and commercial zones seem to be affected..

I'm also facing a bit of a crime spree in my city since this happened, i placed 3 police stations in my city to clean this up but with very little luck.
My biggest concern is that the houses are not being rebuilt, thus i am losing population and income.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have residential demand? It can take some time for houses to become needed, especially if your current residential areas are fulfilling the working needs of your city. Have you tried zoning more industry/commercial too?

The game is a balancing act, ensuring there is demand of people/goods etc so you can supply more and continue this. Main thing is to check your demands for zones and what levels of zones (perhaps you have no demand for low level housing, so you need to improve other areas first to meet the higher level demands?)

As for the crime issue, that will likely take some time to clean up, but it will right itself eventually if you have 3 stations.

Without seeing pictures of your game, only ideas can be given really

Comment: Its actually my more fancy side of town but i'll add a picture

Comment: In that case, have you lost demand for high end housing? Do you still have high tiered jobs? intriguing, I automatically assumed the low end as that is usually what gets hit when i go afk

Comment: No it appears i only need working class atm, i'm going to assume thats why my fancy neighborhood is a grass zone atm

Comment: In that case, zone up for some working class, and improve your businesses for some higher class demand, and you will be back on track. The crime will come under control given time, problem with that is response time, so the amount of police in each station, their location and ultimately traffic flow. Good luck getting your game back on track, its always hard to get back after a long afk on management games